# Kafka commit offset

Tags: apache-kafka, offset

In case of manual commit offset in Kafka, what happens when there is a failure?
Example -> Lets assume offset 0 is committed, offset 1 is ***not*** committed and then offset 2 is committed. Is the message at offset 1 retried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you commit:

On `commitSync` assuming you commit each offset separately like in your example, if offset 1 is not committed it will retry to commit that offset until it succeeds or until it encounters nonRetryable failure.
One drawback of that mechanism is that the application is blocked until the broker responds and therefor limit the application throughput.

On `commitAsync` on the other hand, there is no retry in case it failed to commit offset 1. The reason for that is that by the time the broker responds get back to your Kafka client there may be later commit that was already successful.
Imagine on your example that commit of message with offset 1 was failed due to temporary network issue. Meanwhile the application already processed successfully message with offset 2.  If we now retry previous failed commit it might succeed to commit offset 1 **after** 2 was already committed. In a case of rebalance, this will cause more duplicated.

Comment: From Javadoc - _Offsets committed through multiple calls to [commitAsync] are guaranteed to be sent in the same order as the invocations_... So that implies if there's a retry, shouldn't it still be ordered (at least within the same consumer instance)?

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question as there is no retry for async (as I mentioned in my answer). Note that the calls are in the order of the invocations. But in my example Kafka had network issues so commit offset 1 never arrived to the broker, meanwhile offset 2 was committed successfully .